# DoubleRenderError with no_content return and no other code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following function in my controller:

```
api! 'Destroy a book'
def destroy
  head :no_content
  return
  ....
end
```

But everytime I call my method I get a double render error!

```
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

What could possibly be causing this? I have a before_destroy on my book model defined, but if Im correct that's a) not being called and b) even if it was, still couldnt cause a double render.

It's worth noting that if I reverse the order of the two lines I get a "no template" error, which I believe is what happens if you don't specify a render or redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the class that my controller inherited from. The controller never specified an authorization so it was trying to render the login page. Thats why the controller gave a double render error.